# clean index names in my dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
                          test1     test2     test3
water(h20)                  ok         x         x
carbon dioxide (co2)         x         x         x
Silicon                     ok        ok        ok
```

Could could i clean the df's index by removing the brackets and everything inside?

Desired output:

```
                    test1     test2     test3
water                 ok         x         x
carbon dioxide         x         x         x
Silicon               ok        ok        ok
```

I have tried this code:

```
new_df=df.index.map(lambda x:str(x)[:-5])
```

And works, but does not differentiate those index names with - without brackets (`silicon`), and that is the main issue I am facing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by regex -`\s*` select whitespaces (`*` means `0` or more whitespaces) and then select content of `()` and replace it by empty space:

```
print (df.index.str.replace('\s*\((.*)\)', ''))
Index(['water', 'carbon dioxide', 'Silicon'], dtype='object')

df.index = df.index.str.replace('\s*\((.*)\)', '')
print (df)
               test1 test2 test3
water             ok     x     x
carbon dioxide     x     x     x
Silicon           ok    ok    ok
```

Also if need replace all content from first `(` to end only remove `\)`:

```
print (df)
                     test1 test2 test3
water(h20) ee           ok     x     x
carbon dioxide (co2)     x     x     x
Silicon                 ok    ok    ok

df.index = df.index.str.replace('\s*\((.*)', '')
print (df)
               test1 test2 test3
water             ok     x     x
carbon dioxide     x     x     x
Silicon           ok    ok    ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
In [961]: df.index = df.index.str.split('(').str[0]

In [962]: df
Out[962]:
                test1 test2 test3
water              ok     x     x
carbon dioxide      x     x     x
Silicon            ok    ok    ok
```